# How to kill a thread in Haskell

Tags: windows, multithreading, haskell, signals, ghc

Using Control.Concurrent and forkIO, there are some cases that will leave the thread in a blocked state (this is especially frequent under Windows with networking) so even if one tries to use killThread the exception is never raised in the thread.

Is there any other way to force a thread to die?

My attempt to terminate the whole application with exitFailure from a helper thread didn't have any effect under these conditions.

I'm using the Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 6.12.1
HP 2010.1.0.0

EDIT: To clear things up, I don't want to terminate the application, I would prefer to just kill the thread that have been blocked for a very long time.

However, there are numerous examples even here on SO with complete code using exitWith in a helper thread and that kind of scheme doesn't work under the conditions I have.

Comment: Do you have an example? Other than being blocked on a foreign call, what cases are you thinking of?

Comment: I could probably create a small example but when using Network-ByteString (0.1.3) and recv under windows7/vista/2003/2008/2008r2 the recv will block until some network condition happens. I would like to just scrap that connection and restart, (ie timeout) without exit the entire application.

Comment: What I want todo Don is a poormans supervisor (erlang) but using lightweight haskell threads. I can't change the server and I can't use socketoption to time-out the recv, the time-out need to be calculated from other criteria that are not given until very late in the programs lifespan.

Comment: you can switch to nonblocking IO for the recv. At the cost of some performance, just spin on nonblocking reads from the socket...

Comment: Maybe the correct answer really is that you can't kill a thread. You may request a thread to die but you can't be sure it will die.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on my comment above, you can't interrupt blocking foreign calls. You can, however, use nonblocking IO. In the case of the Network package, this means `recvLen` for strings, and `recvFrom` for bytestrings. I assume you're always specifying the threaded runtime as well?

Comment: This is to this point the closest thing to an answer yet, however I can't use it in my particular problem. I can however put the socket in an MVar and close the socket in my supervisor thread  to get the effect I  need, if I put the killThread call before the close socket.

Answer (score 3):

One other thing to note is that GHC programs terminate when the main thread terminates.  The liveness of child threads is unimportant.  If you design your app such that you can always signal the main thread that it's time to terminate, it doesn't matter how blocked any child threads are.

Comment: This is how I currently have 'solved' the issue but I really would like just to abandon the thread and restart the io that was in the thread.

Answer (score 2):

In Posix environments you can terminate the entire process with:

```
-- | @'exitImmediately' status@ calls @_exit@ to terminate the process
--   with the indicated exit @status@.
--   The operation never returns.
exitImmediately :: ExitCode -> IO ()
```

From [the unix package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unix/2.4.2.0/doc/html/System-Posix-Process.html#g:3). There may be a similar non-Posix feature under the [Win32 package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Win32-2.2.0.2).

However, it is better to design your application such that your signalling mechanisms are respected, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the ExitProcess() API from any thread in your app and the whole process, threads and all, will be terminated.  There are some gotchas with some DLL detaches that can cause an issue and a process cannot be terminated until all handles for it have been released, but ExitProcess() always works fine for me as a last resort.

ExitProcess() does not care what state your threads are in.  The can be blocked on I/O or running on a different processor than the thread that calls ExitProcess() - it does not matter, the OS will stop them all.

Rgds,
Martin