# Can a Haskell or Haskell OS thread waiting on Network.Socket.accept not be killed on Windows?

Tags: multithreading, exception, networking, haskell, asynchronous

```
-- thread A
t <- forkIO $ do
   _ <- accept listener -- blocks
```

---

```
-- thread B
killThread t
```

---

works on Linux (probably also on OS X and FreeBSD) but not on Windows (tried -threaded with +RTS -N4 -RTS etc.).

- What is the correct way to terminate thread `A` in this case?
- Is there a way to fork thread `A` in a special mode that would allow termination at the point it blocks on `accept`?
- Would it help if `A` were forked with `forkOS` rather than `forkIO`?

*I noticed this deviant Windows behaviour only when alerted to by a [bug report](https://github.com/corsis/PortFusion/issues/1).*

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185189/howto-kill-a-thread-in-haskell

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Interesting question!

You can't interrupt blocking foreign calls, so I'm somewhat surprised that you're able to interrupt the thread on Linux. Also, `forkOS` doesn't help -- that just lets foreign code allocate thread-local storage, but has nothing to do with blocking behavior. But recall that accept can be set to non-blocking:

> If no pending connections are present on the queue, and the socket is
>   not marked as nonblocking, accept() blocks the caller until a
>   connection is present. If the socket is marked nonblocking and no
>   pending connections are present on the queue, accept() fails with the
>   error EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK.

Which is what is done [in the Network library for Posix systems.](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/network/2.3.0.13/doc/html/src/Network-Socket.html#accept) This then allows the `accept` to be interrupted.

An interesting note about Windows:

```
-- On Windows, our sockets are not put in non-blocking mode (non-blocking
-- is not supported for regular file descriptors on Windows, and it would
-- be a pain to support it only for sockets).  So there are two cases:
--
--  - the threaded RTS uses safe calls for socket operations to get
--    non-blocking I/O, just like the rest of the I/O library
--
--  - with the non-threaded RTS, only some operations on sockets will be
--    non-blocking.  Reads and writes go through the normal async I/O
--    system.  accept() uses asyncDoProc so is non-blocking.  A handful
--    of others (recvFrom, sendFd, recvFd) will block all threads - if this
--    is a problem, -threaded is the workaround.
```

Now, accept on Windows, with the -threaded runtime, uses accept_safe (which allows other threads to make progress) -- but it doesn't put the socket into non-blocking mode:

```
accept sock@(MkSocket s family stype protocol status) = do
 currentStatus <- readMVar status
 okay <- sIsAcceptable sock
 if not okay
   then
     ioError (userError ("accept: can't perform accept on socket (" ++ (show (family,stype,protocol)) ++") in status " ++
     show currentStatus))
   else do
     let sz = sizeOfSockAddrByFamily family
     allocaBytes sz $ \ sockaddr -> do

#if defined(mingw32_HOST_OS) && defined(__GLASGOW_HASKELL__)
     new_sock <-
    if threaded
       then with (fromIntegral sz) $ \ ptr_len ->
          throwErrnoIfMinus1Retry "Network.Socket.accept" $
            c_accept_safe s sockaddr ptr_len
       else do
            paramData <- c_newAcceptParams s (fromIntegral sz) sockaddr
            rc        <- asyncDoProc c_acceptDoProc paramData
            new_sock  <- c_acceptNewSock    paramData
            c_free paramData
            when (rc /= 0)
                 (ioError (errnoToIOError "Network.Socket.accept" (Errno (fromIntegral rc)) Nothing Nothing))
        return new_sock
```

Since 2005, versions of the `network` package, on Windows with -threaded explicitly use an accept call marked as `safe`, allowing other threads to make progress, but not setting the socket itself into non-blocking mode (so the calling thread blocks).

To work around it I see two options:

- work out how to make a non-blocking accept call on Windows, and patch the network library -- look at what e.g. snap or yesod do here, to see if they already solved it.
- use some kind of supervisory thread to fake epoll, monitoring the blocked child threads for progress.

Comment: *Wow!!* Thanks to your code except I found a good quick fix. I saw that with the non-threaded runtime they are doing `asyncDoProc` calls and these can be interrupted :) So on Windows I will just default to that runtime until I figure out a better solution.

Comment: Yeah, we need to get the non-blocking accept on by default for Windows.

Comment: I will also confirm and post whether I can really interrupt `accept` on Linux in this particular case.

Comment: I just checked and confirm that `accept` is interruptible on Linux (OS X and FreeBSD may be the same as Linux).