# Haskell MongoDB Issue (close pipe)?

Tags: mongodb, haskell, driver

Using this driver:

https://github.com/TonyGen/mongoDB-haskell

I cannot close the pipe (connection) to MongoDB.  I can actually do other things like successfully insert stuff into the database, I just can't close the pipe afterwards.

I would like to confirm or deny whether the issue is the driver itself.  Can someone confirm/deny?

I am using the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, ExtendedDefaultRules #-}

import Database.MongoDB
import Control.Monad.Trans (liftIO)

main = do
    pipe <- runIOE $ connect (host "127.0.0.1")
    close pipe
```

UPDATE:  To answer a few questions, after running the code it just sits there (locks up).  The freezing occurs on the 'close pipe' statement.  It never returns from that command no matter how long I let it sit there, and I can't do anything else unless I CTRL-C out.

I'd like someone else using the same driver to run this code and tell me what happens.

Comment: what happens when you use the close pipe then?

Comment: I think that the pipe itself is not the actual tcp/ip/unixsocket handle. So I definitely think that your pipe is closed but maybe the handle isn't (but will be after a while). The close statement will send a killthread to the listenpart of the pipe and close the stream

Comment: See update on question.

Comment: Under what os ? win32/linux/mac ?

Comment: I assume that you have compiled your example with ghc -threaded

Comment: Things you should always add to your post with haskell/ghc, ghc version, how you compile or run, the os you are using. If you are using the Haskell platform, which version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source

```
 hGetN :: Handle -> Int -> IO ByteString
-- ^ Read N bytes from hande, blocking until all N bytes are read. If EOF is reached before N bytes then raise EOF exception.
hGetN h n = assert (n >= 0) $ do
bytes <- hGet h n
let x = fromEnum $ S.length bytes
if x >= n then return bytes
else if x == 0 then ioError (mkIOError eofErrorType "hGetN" (Just h) Nothing)
else S.append bytes <$> hGetN h (n - x)
```

so if one take a look on my old post [Howto kill a thread in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185189/howto-kill-a-thread-in-haskell) I think it's very likely that the pipe listen thread is "stuck" on hGet, waiting for more data.

There are a couple of ways around this but I think that basically the driver is doing it wrong. 
Ie one must close the socket from a helper thread.

Comment: strange that no one else seems to have complained about the issue.  Unless someone else comes up with a better answer, I'll accept yours.